# Permission Denied error while running start-dfs.sh

Tags: sockets, hadoop, hdfs, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

I am getting this error while performing `start-dfs.sh`

```
Starting namenodes on [localhost] 
pdsh@Gaurav: localhost: rcmd: socket: Permission denied 
Starting datanodes
pdsh@Gaurav: localhost: rcmd: socket: Permission denied
Starting secondary namenodes [Gaurav]
pdsh@Gaurav: Gaurav: rcmd: socket: Permission denied 2017-03-13 09:39:29,559 
WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
```

Using hadoop 3.0 alpha 2 version.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: This might help you http://pka.engr.ccny.cuny.edu/~jmao/node/57

Comment: Hey BATMAN.... The above url didnt work....

Comment: Thanks a lot, it took me hours of try and erros. My setup was ubuntu server 22.04 and hadoop 3.3.4. Cheers!

Answer (score 73):

I also encountered the same thing, I did so
I found that my pdsh default rcmd is rsh, not ssh, rsh and ssh remote login authentication is not the same, when installing hadoop I configured ssh localhost password-free login, but rsh is not possible.

so，try：

1.check your pdsh default rcmd rsh

```
pdsh -q -w localhost
```

See what your pdsh default rcmd is.

2.Modify pdsh's default rcmd to ssh

```
export PDSH_RCMD_TYPE=ssh
```

you can be added to ~/.bashrc, and `source ~/.bashrc`

3.`sbin / start-dfs.sh`

Comment: You're great. It definitely worked for me. The people probably set-up it over ssh. But this setting was rsh. This is correct solution.

Comment: The best resolution on the web so far, Thanks a lot, it took me hours of try and erros. My setup was ubuntu server 22.04 and hadoop 3.3.4. Cheers! –

Comment: Yes, "connect: Connection refused", big deal.

Answer (score 9):

Uninstall `pdsh` will solve this problem. I am working with Hadoop version 3.2.1 on Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS.

I test `start-dfs.sh` on several fresh-installed virtual machines and one old VM. The command failed only on the old VM. I have tried the [high-voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48415037/6571140), and found that only the old VM has `pdsh` installed. So I uninstall this software, and after that the command executed successfully.

So, if you did not install `pdsh` for some purpose, you can try to uninstall it.

Comment: This worked for me too. `pdsh` is not an absolute requirement. From the docs -

`Additionally, it is recommmended that pdsh also be installed for better ssh resource management.`

Comment: after removing pdsh i got ```ERROR: JAVA_HOME is not set and could not be found.``` I don't think it was to be removed.

Comment: @Lawhatre `JAVA_HOME` can be explicitly set in `HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh` or `HOME/.bashrc` or `/etc/profile.d/hadoop.sh`. Make sure that JDK/JRE have been installed on your system.

Answer (score 9):

Try uninstalling pdsh

`sudo apt-get remove pdsh`

and then restart your hadoop by:

`sudo start-dfs.sh`

This is what worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

A sudo user could also change pdsh's Rcmd type to ssh via the command:

`echo "ssh" | sudo tee /etc/pdsh/rcmd_default`

Answer (score 0):

Try with `sudo`

Example:

```
sudo start-dfs.sh
```

Otherwise change the owner of the folder hadoop_1.2.7

Example:

```
sudo chown -R user_name:user_name hadoop_1.2.7
```

Comment: Hi! thanks for the help... The problem was occurring due to 3.0 alpha 2. When I repeated process in hadoop2.7 it solved the problem...